Why is my GroupController method not pulling the posts that have group id as foreign key?
In my Laravel application I have two tables: groups and posts. In posts, I have the groups.id as a foreign key as the posts will belong to a specific group. I am getting the error Attempt to read property "title" on bool as I am trying to loop through the posts in the blade template file. I know that normally means it failed, but there is data in the posts table. How can I pull all posts that belong to their respective group?
GroupController.php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Group;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class GroupController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     */
    public function show(string $id)
    {
        $posts = Group::with('posts')->find($id);

        return view('groups.single-group', compact('posts'));
    }
}

Routes
Route::prefix('group')->middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/{id}', [GroupController::class, 'show'])->name('group-page');
});

Models
class Group extends Model
{

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }


}

class Post extends Model
{

    public function group()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Group::class);
    }
}


Are you sure that your two foreign keys are named as posts_id & groups_id? Naming convention might cause error. What is your full access url in browse??

You told us you have a groups.id column, but what about the posts table?  From the docs: "By convention, Eloquent will take the "snake case" name of the parent model and suffix it with _id".  So your posts table should have a group_id field (contrary to previous comment it should be singular, not plural, and you do not need a groups.post_id field).  What debugging have you tried?  Eg in your controller does dd(Group::find($id)); return the model as expected?

@Don'tPanic, yes right you are.It must be singual.Thanks for the correction.
